# Python caching for multiple users

Tags: python, django, caching, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm creating a python wrapper for Vimeo API and this is my first time creating a python distribution. I'm having questions with **python caching**.

I referred this [existing python-vimeo wrapper](https://github.com/dkm/python-vimeo/blob/master/vimeo/__init__.py) for caching the request token. That guy implemented like this

```
"""By default, this client will cache API requests for 120 seconds. To
override this setting, pass in a different cache_timeout parameter (in
seconds), or to disable caching, set cache_timeout to 0."""
```

I'm wondering whether it will create a problem or not. If there is **more than one user** using that feature for connecting vimeo exactly at the **same time**, and storing the information like this in the server

```
return self._cache.setdefault(key, processor(headers, content))
```

doesn't it create problem(informations will be **overwritten in the cache**)?

If it creates a problem, could you tell me the best solution? I think It would be storing in the filename with the name of authenticated username. Am I right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the issue, but you could create a prefixed key where the prefix of the key is the username. So a naive but possibly good approach is to save to the

> username+"_"+key

key instead

There most likely wouldn't be any key collisions.